# Как отслеживать изменения в ячейке PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Здраствуйте.
Искал, как можна отслеживать смену содержимого в ячейке, что бы потом брать значение из них и использовать в других операциях. Но мои поиски не увенчались успехом.

Таблица создается циклом:

```
def addItemName():
    try:
        for i in range(len(get_tovaru()['names'])):
            rowPosition = ui.table_product.rowCount()
            ui.table_product.insertRow(rowPosition)
            ui.table_product.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(get_tovaru()['names'][i]))
            print((get_tovaru()['names']))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

def addItemPhoto():
    try:
        for i in range(len(get_tovaru()['names'])):
            rowPosition = ui.table_product.rowCount()
            ui.table_product.insertRow(rowPosition)

            #getImage().downloadimage()

            pic = QPixmap(f'photos/img_{i}.jpg')
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setPixmap(pic)
            label.setGeometry(0,0, 500, 500)

            ui.table_product.setCellWidget(i, 1, label)

            print((get_tovaru()['photo']))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        print(get_tovaru()['photo'][0])

def addItemCharesteristic():
    try:
        for i in range(len(get_tovaru()['names'])):
            rowPosition = ui.table_product.rowCount()
            ui.table_product.insertRow(rowPosition)
            ui.table_product.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(get_tovaru()['charesteristic'][i]))
            print((get_tovaru()['charesteristic']))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

def addPriceGrn():
    try:
        for i in range(len(get_tovaru()['names'])):
            rowPosition = ui.table_product.rowCount()
            ui.table_product.insertRow(rowPosition)
            ui.table_product.setItem(i, 3, QTableWidgetItem(get_tovaru()['price_grn'][i]))
            print((get_tovaru()['price_ryb']))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

def addPriceDol():
    try:
        for i in range(len(get_tovaru()['names'])):
            rowPosition = ui.table_product.rowCount()
            ui.table_product.insertRow(rowPosition)
            ui.table_product.setItem(i, 4, QTableWidgetItem(get_tovaru()['price_dol'][i]))
            print((get_tovaru()['price_dol']))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Для отслеживания изменения данных в таблице, необходимо использовать **QTableView** + **QAbstructItemModel**. Вместо **QAbstructItemModel** можно использовать любой удобный класс модели, например **QStandardItemModel**, **QAbstractTableModel**. Для отслеживания изменений, нужно переопределить метод
`bool QAbstractItemModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)`
у модели или подписаться на сигнал
`void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = QVector<int>())`
у модели. Сигнатура метода **setData** и сигнала **dataChanged** в QT C++ полностью соответствует PyQT.
Ссылка на документацию QT: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html